# Travel Insurance for US Citizens for a year-long trip

Tags: australia, us-citizens, insurance, backpacking

In a few months, I will be going to Australia on a Work and Holiday Visa for a year to travel and work. I am looking for a place to get health/travel insurance for my time there. Does anyone know of any good companies to do this (for US citizens)? In addition, I would like to have "sports" coverage as I intend on SCUBA diving, skydiving, etc.

Lastly, I will be graduating from college and my health insurance will be ending about when I leave. Therefore, I was wondering if it is possible to get some travel/health insurance that stands on its own and that I don't need a primary insurance back home.

Comment: From the UK at least, the magic phrase to search for would be "gap year insurance"

Answer (score 6):

There are options with local health insurers for $19-$25 AUD a week. This seems to be a common choice instead of getting travel insurance, however this will depend on your circumstances.

If you lookup "health insurance australia visa" you should find them.

The two main companies are [Bupa](http://www.bupa.com.au/health-insurance/cover/overseas-visitors) and [Medibank](http://www.medibank.com.au/client/staticpages/vchome.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of companies offering insurance to long term travellers including work and holiday workers or round-the-world tourists.

[Avi-international](http://en.avi-international.com/our-insurance-packages/workingholiday/insurance-working-holiday) targets all nationalities but requires you to be under 35 - which should be the case for a work and holiday visa.

[World Nomads](http://service.worldnomads.com/customer/portal/articles/1063154--i-m-on-a-working-holiday) apparently is not clear on that point for us citizens even though it covers working holidays for other countries' citizens.

There are a few others that you should be able to find through a search engine.